# LT3663 regulating low

Tags: switching-regulator, low-voltage

I have a simple [LT3663](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3663fc.pdf) circuit that I'm using to regulate 15v down to 13.8v.

[image]

("24v" is actually 15v in, and "15v" is 13.8v out.) This works almost perfectly. It current limits properly, etc. However, for some reason, the LT3663 only outputs 10.4v, at any current draw below the limit. It regulates perfectly at this voltage. Messing around with R18 and R20 values didn't change anything at all.

Layout:

[image]

It's...a bit ugly. However, I think it's pretty close to the reference in terms of placement and grounding and routing.

Why is this?

EDIT:

Something very odd is happening, indeed. I just pulled R18 off the board completely (grounding FB), and the vreg still maintains 10.2v.

Comment: How does your board layout look? Did you follow the recommended pcb layout? And are you using the right type of diode on SW? And the inductor is chosen for its specs or just any 15 µh?

Comment: @Passerby Oh no not the kittens! I'm sorry, puppies. I'll try and clean it up. Board layout is reasonably close to stock, I'll post a pic. Inductor has a saturation of 1.1a (only running about 200ma), resistance of 200 milliohm. NRS5020T150MMGJ

Comment: -1 for the messy schematic, and voting to close since I stopped there and don't know what is being asked.  You wouldn't hand in homework this sloppy.  We deserve at least the same respect as your teachers.

Comment: @Passerby Cleaned up the labels. Sorry about how bad it looked, rush prototype :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably running into the LT3663's maximum duty-cycle limit as well as other internal losses.
The datasheet specifies the duty-cycle limit as: typical 92%, minimum 80%.
So if you hope for the typical value and assume 100% efficiency everywhere else, the best you could get is 13.8V
But since efficiency is never 100%, you have a diode drop, and you can't bet on getting the typical value, you shouldn't expect as much as 13.8V out.
Taking into account a lower max duty-cycle, some diode drop and other losses (transistor switch, inductor, current-sense, etc), your 10.4V is not surprising.

***EDIT:***
I'm surprised *somone* didn't spot this sooner, but you should really have a look at the top of page 2 of the datasheet - particularly where it lists the **Absolute Maximum Ratings** for the **Vout** pin (amongst others) as ***6V !!!***
That IC is apparently not intended to be used for anything much above 5V output - even the adjustable version.
**A check on Linear's product selector grid, with VOut Max column enabled shows *5.5V* as the maximum output voltage.**
None of the application circuits show anything above 5V either.
I hope for your sake that LT has a pin-compatible substitute ....

Comment: Whoa, min duty cycle is 80%? I'm getting 70. That's wierd.

Comment: You read his answer wrong.  The maximum duty cycle can occur in a range between 80% and 92%.  The minimum duty cycle is not specified since this part uses 'pulse skipping'.  The minimum switch on time is on page four of the [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3663fc.pdf).

Comment: @slight Oh, oops. My bad.

Comment: @DC177E - ping - see edit ....

Comment: Linear's website and datasheets suck. I had to use the product selector for the category and show the hidden VOUT max column to find the max recommended VOUT. http://www.linear.com/parametric/Internal_Power_Switch_Buck#!cols_1031,2167,1107,1367,1036,1033,1032,1034,1105!s_1107,0!gtd_!0_lt3663  TI doesn't have the problem, they have nice grids right on the product page.

Comment: Came here to say this.  Yep, this part is not meant to output more than 5.5V really.  It has over voltage protection on the INPUT, but not the output.  It would seem that one can make this chip regulate the output to the point of it's own damage, and whatever the failure mechanism was, its burned something up and now it's permanently locked to 10.4V regardless of the feedback.  Certainly an interesting failure mode.  But yeah, this is one of those unfortunate 'datasheet gotchyas'.

Comment: Wow, so then Digikey screwed up! Digikey lists the Vout Max as 33v.

Comment: @DC177E it happens more than you'd expect.

Comment: @Passerby You and metacollin solved it with the edit, thanks so much everyone! And no, there's no drop in replacement, naturally, so revision 9 of this dang board required...

Answer (score 2):

You have a diode on the OUT pin that is causing your voltage to drop.  Remove the diode.  The [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3663fc.pdf) shows no diode in their sample circuit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't; there's voltage on the output most of the time and it'll backfeed into the regulator.

Comment: The diode only has a drop of about 0.6v, however, so it seems like that wouldn't affect it this much?

Comment: @DC177E It could have something to do w/ how close the output voltage is to the input voltage.  Try an experiment, bring the input voltage to 20V and run all of your testing.  If you are looking for 13.8V out, you have 15V - diode drop - switch drop, you might actually be at or near 100% duty cycle and, thus, have no real control of the output.

Comment: I've tried running all they way up to 17v, and it still regulated at ~10v. Across the diode there's 0.4v right now. Duty cycle is about 70%.

Comment: Try it up to 20V.  That should give some real head room.  Also, is your inductor low resistance?  Ceramic caps?  The part is a reasonably simple part, so there aren't that many things to go wrong... When you look on a scope, is the output a nice even DC with low ripple?

Comment: Output's very clean. All ceramic caps, yep, except I've got a big bulk electrolytic on the output pretty far away. Inductor is 0.2 ohm. Just tried it to 20v, no change in output.

Comment: How big is the bulk capacitor?

Comment: 1500uf. Pretty big. This board takes surges of 15a at times.

Comment: Whoa!  This is a 1.2A part.  I suggest removing that capacitor and verifying your power supply circuit.  After you get that going, then you should see if you have an issue supplying voltage to other parts of the circuit before adding such a huge capacitor on this regulator.  I am not sure if this is your problem, but I have seen stranger things.

Comment: Actually, after a bit of thought, I believe that - in charging this huge capacitance - your circuit is basically going into current-limit (the switch is turning off) before you can fully charge your output circuit.  Definitely remove the large cap.

Comment: Actually in the circuit I have now, the cap is pre-charged when the regulator starts up. (This is part of a ups system, and the system starts up directly connected to a battery, [charging the cap], then the regulator is switched on in software)

Comment: I took R18 completely off just now and the regulator still maintained 10.4v, which is odd.

Comment: Re populate your circuit and try removing the large cap.  If your circuit is always in current limit, your are basically in open-loop operation anyway and your feedback resistors don't matter.

Comment: done. Still maintains 10.2v, but only for a few seconds. Seems to be unstable; after a few seconds, it starts putting huge 2v ripple on the line and making audible noise.

Comment: OOPS. That ripple was my fault. I shorted across ISENSE and OUT  when I was putting the resistor back in. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Still only regulating at 10v, however.

Comment: Ok, and what kind of current is the circuit drawing?

Comment: Under 150 milliamps.

Comment: I'm stumped.  If you have a blank board, start checking the connections with an ohmmeter.  Maybe try a new IC in case that one is damaged.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for all your help, wish I could give rep somehow.

Comment: Are you certain you have a  LT3663, or is it a LT3663-5 for example? the -5 version is a fixed voltage part which you would expect to always have 5V output, but pin 3 has a different function (Vouts rather than FB) and I'm not sure what it does when its not connected correctly. Maybe it always gives 10.2V?